# Remote host not finding functions in an included file for SQL (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, c, linker-errors

I am developing on my Rasp Pi, and I am doing it via LAN from my PC. So far no issues, however I have included the SQL library as `#include <mysql.h>` in C.

I have the `mysql` folder installed in `/usr/include/mysql` inside of which is `mysql.h`. I also have this as a local copy on my system, and I have added the path to `/usr/include/mysql` in the additional library directories in the `Linker` part of the C compiler.

When I attempt a connection (as per the direction on their website) via:

```
 /* Connect to database */
    if (!mysql_real_connect(conn, server,
        user, password, database, 0, NULL, 0)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
        exit(1);
    }else{
       printf("Connected");
    }
```

I build the code and this error comes up in the error console:

```
/root/.netbeans/remote/192.168.1.132/ian-pc-Windows-x86_64/C/Users/Ian/Documents/NetBeansProjects/gpsComplete/gpsd-3.15/dbConnect.c:21: undefined reference to `mysql_init'
/root/.netbeans/remote/192.168.1.132/ian-pc-Windows-x86_64/C/Users/Ian/Documents/NetBeansProjects/gpsComplete/gpsd-3.15/dbConnect.c:24: undefined reference to `mysql_real_connect'
/root/.netbeans/remote/192.168.1.132/ian-pc-Windows-x86_64/C/Users/Ian/Documents/NetBeansProjects/gpsComplete/gpsd-3.15/dbConnect.c:26: undefined reference to `mysql_error'
```

I have tried linking the library multipul times, removing the files etc and nothing will change this. Am I missing something when developing remotely? I am struggling with libraries in remote development so far

Comment: "I run the code ..." Please get the phrases right: you **build** the code. **Running** the code means you start the **built** program after successful build. Note: that is a linker error. You should check the library paths.

Comment: @Olaf sorry, thanks for pointing that out to me! I have edited my post. The library path `/usr/include/mysql` is correct, I have checked on the filesystem on the Rasp Pi